# Vue: How can i use the data gotten from APi as Slug

Tags: api, vue.js, slug

Presently I have built my app, it is working perfectly, however, I do not want the url to show my id, for instance  my url is presently
`www.example/product/23`. Instead of that, I want to have `www.example/product/product-name`.

The API in which the data is coming from is `endpointURL.com/product/id`
In my Vue router

```js
{
  path: "/product/:id",
  name: "product", 
  component: product
},
```

If I change the path `/product/:slug`, it generates an error.

I really need it to change the url to `/slug`.

Comment: in that case, you might want to use hashids to hide your id
https://www.npmjs.com/package/hashids
if you want it to be slug, you need to create slug property/field in you db and make it unique

Comment: Like @RobertAnthonyS.Tribiana said, the easiest path for you, is to just create a `endpointURL.com/product/slug` API endpoint, and have this API retrieve the product using the slug instead of the id.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen thanks, that worked for me , creating endpointURL.com/product/slug solve the whole stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this case, i had to create an endpoint from the backend ,e.g  endpointURL.com/product/slug